# R crypto2: How to retreive global market cap historical data?

Tags: r, cryptocurrency

I would like to retreive the historical global marketcap from Coinmarketcap.com with the help of the `crypto2` R package. Unfortunately, I haven't found the respective function in the package reference.

- I know that there is an alternative package called `coinmarketcapr` that provides an explicit function to do exactly that but it requires an official API and costly Coinmarketcap subscription in order to retreive all historical data. In contrast, the `crypto2` package scrapes the data directly and doesn't go through the API.
- I also know that there is a possibility to use the `crypto_history` function in the `crypto2` for all coins and aggregate them but scraping the data just in order to get the global market cap takes hours in computing time.

This is the code that I am using so far:

```
library(crypto2)

crypto_history(
  coin_list = NULL,
  convert = "USD",
  start_date = as.Date("2020-01-01"),
  end_date = as.Date(Sys.Date()),
  interval = "daily",
  sleep = 60,
  finalWait = TRUE
)
```

The abovementioned code returns a tibble/dataframe object with all coins including some fundamental data such as OHLC prices as well as the market cap that needs to be aggregated across all individual coins in order to receive the overall marekt cap.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Of course, I will use the data for educational/non-commercial uses only.

Thank you very much in advance for your help!